# Updating a PriorityQueue

Tags: python, python-3.x, priority-queue

I'm extremely confused about the different behavior of `PriorityQueue` when the item is an integer versus a string. But before addressing that, I'd like to understand the following behavior (using items as integers).

Suppose I have a priority queue with the following data (for each element, the first value is the priority and the second value is an item):

Image 1:

[image]

After I execute the following commands:

```
pq.put(pq.get())
```

The elements become sorted as follows:

Image 2:

[image]

Why have some elements changed places? What's going on with the sorting?

Here's the code to reproduce these screenshots from the debugger:

```
from sys import maxsize
from queue import PriorityQueue

items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 17, 15, 16]
INFINITY = maxsize
minDist = {k: INFINITY for k in items}
minDist[3] = 0

pq = PriorityQueue(len(minDist))

for v in minDist.keys():
    pq.put([minDist[v], v])

# At this point, pq has the elements as shown in Image 1

pq.put(pq.get())

# Now, pq has elements scrambled as shown in Image 2
```

**LESSONS LEARNED**

Based on the investigations and discussions below, each call to `pq.put(pq.get())` will rearrange the priority queue data structure. It's not clear if there's a way to control that. Please comment below if you know how!

My specific problem seems to be related to the sorting of items. As shown in Images 1 and 2, the items are integers from 1 to 17. If they're converted to strings (i.e., `"1"`, `"2"`, ..., `"17"`), I was getting a different behavior from the main function in my original code. However, if I use `zfill(2)` for each key, so that I have `"01"`, `"02"`, ..., `"17"`, I'm able to get the same final results as what I get if I use integers instead.

Comment: I can't share the original code and was hoping the images would be sufficient to supplement my questions. I'll add some simple code as per your request.

Comment: Updated with sample code.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear to me what is happening in the screenshots you show, but an example session with the interpreter is shown below that tries to recreate the problem with a slightly different approach:

```
Python 3.8.2 (tags/v3.8.2:7b3ab59, Feb 25 2020, 23:03:10) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> import math, pprint, queue
>>> min_dist = {x: math.inf for x in range(1, 17)}
>>> min_dist[3] = 0
>>> pq = queue.PriorityQueue(len(min_dist))
>>> for key, value in min_dist.items():
    pq.put((value, key))


>>> pq_items = []
>>> while not pq.empty():
    pq_items.append(pq.get())


>>> pprint.pprint(pq_items)
[(0, 3),
 (inf, 1),
 (inf, 2),
 (inf, 4),
 (inf, 5),
 (inf, 6),
 (inf, 7),
 (inf, 8),
 (inf, 9),
 (inf, 10),
 (inf, 11),
 (inf, 12),
 (inf, 13),
 (inf, 14),
 (inf, 15),
 (inf, 16)]
>>> for key, value in min_dist.items():
    pq.put((value, key))


>>> pq.put(pq.get())
>>> pq_items.clear()
>>> while not pq.empty():
    pq_items.append(pq.get())


>>> pprint.pprint(pq_items)
[(0, 3),
 (inf, 1),
 (inf, 2),
 (inf, 4),
 (inf, 5),
 (inf, 6),
 (inf, 7),
 (inf, 8),
 (inf, 9),
 (inf, 10),
 (inf, 11),
 (inf, 12),
 (inf, 13),
 (inf, 14),
 (inf, 15),
 (inf, 16)]
>>>
```

You may want to adapt your code to use a similar approach to get what you are looking for. If you are having trouble with strings, then you may want to examine how your elements would be ordered if they were put into a list and then sorted.

Comment: Thanks! After making one small change to your code (I defined `items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 17, 15, 16]` to replace `range(1, 17)` just so it matches mine exactly, and if I add a breakpoint at the command `pq_items.clear()`, i.e., right after the command `pq.put(pq.get())`, the data in `pq` is exactly what I show in Image 2. The order is scrambled. Apparently, for every `pq.get()`, the items get scrambled. And if all of them have the same priority, they'll get rearranged in an "unpredictable" way.

Comment: Just use the debugger and go line by line to inspect what happens to the data in `pq` after every `pq.get()` call. The elements get rearranged even if their priority is the same.

Comment: @Bruno If you look at `pq.queue`, then you are right. The order of the elements within the underlying data structure can change order. However as shown in my answer, the effective order of the elements as they come out of the `PriorityQueue` instance is the same.

Comment: Yeah, just realized it now. Thanks for the insights. I adapted the code from http://www.geekviewpoint.com/python/graph/dijkstra_constrained so that `minDist` is a dictionary of dictionaries instead of a list of lists. The motivation was to allow very general keys to be used (`int`, `str`, etc.). The problem I'm facing, and that influenced this question, is that when I have the keys as strings for a specific example, the adapted code doesn't work in the same way as if the keys were integers. This is driving me crazy! A smaller example works just fine regardless if I use strings or integers.

Comment: See function `updatePriorityQueue` in the link above. That's why I was asking about `pq.put(pq.get())`. Because items get rearranged differently after every call to such function, if they're integers vs. strings, that changes the behavior of the main function only because of the key types and even if the associated values are the same.

Comment: Alright, I found the "problem". Will update my original post.

Comment: @Bruno The items in the `queue` attribute of your `PriorityQueue` instance should probably not be examined or accessed directly. While there are no underscores at the beginning of the attribute's name, it may be helpful to think of it as a private rather than a public attribute. Try using the `PriorityQueue` instance's methods instead. If on the other hand you want to manage the `queue` attribute directly, you could take a lighter weight approach by using the `heapq` module directly. `PriorityQueue` inherits a lot of code from `Queue` that you may not need and wraps `heapq` functionality.

Comment: Thanks. I did try a pure `heapq` approach, but it was giving me the same results. It has something to do with sorting the items. `"1"` and `"01"` get sorted differently. I'm still not sure how to enforce a "deterministic" outcome regardless of the item type.

Comment: Look at Image 2 in my post. Why, after executing `pq.put(pq.get())`, item 1 comes before 6 which comes before 2 etc.? Item 8 was put last. It does seem to be deterministic. But I can't figure out the logic for this to happen. And if I use strings, I'll only get the equivalent behavior if I use `zfill(2)`. This is very weird to me!

Comment: @Bruno You may want to read this documentation: [heapq — Heap queue algorithm](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html) The `PriorityQueue` class does the same thing as the `heapq` module because the class' methods use the module's functions. A heap queue (AKA priority queue) is not supposed to keep items in sorted order. If that is what you want, take a look at this: [bisect — Array bisection algorithm](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html) As for the order of your strings, you should stick them in a `list` and use the `sort` method to see how they are naturally put in order.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211250/discussion-between-noctis-skytower-and-bruno).